# Hide the "Page" button on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What is the easiest way to hide the "Page" link?

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's are code behind and client side ways of hiding the Page tab

**Code Behind:**

via MSDN forums [Hide/disable ribbon items](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/aa762bd7-2702-4108-a534-14a72a4e7062):

```
public void HideRibbonItem()
{
    //if this is a System.Web.UI.Page
    SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this);
    ribbon.TrimById("Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewFolder");
}
```

and from [Default Server Ribbon Customization Locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543(en-us,office.14).aspx) it is the `Ribbon.WebPartPage` tab

**javascript/jQuery:**

inspecting the page we can see the Page tab is buried deep

[image: SP2010-Page-tab-element]

but with some quick and dirty javascript or jQuery you can hide that tab

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('Ribbon.WebPartPage-title').style.display = "none";
```

jQuery:

```
$('#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title').hide();
```

---

I'd consider the code-behind method to be the cleaner way but client side script gets the job done as well.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this on the master page?

Comment: Maybe consider adding a custom user control with code-behind to your masterpage

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the solution mentioned here already, to hide the page tab completely you should use `Ribbon.WebPartPage` instead of `Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewFolder`.